# Sharepoint 2010 custom webpart paging

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to implement simple paging on my sharepoint webpart. I have a single news articles list which has some simple columns. I want to be able to have then five on a page and with some numerical paging at the bottom. I have gone through the net trying to understand splistitemcollectionposition but with no luck. If anyone can help please can you give me a simple code example or some guidanc

Many thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using SPDataSource and a SPGridView, together they will implement paging and many other cool features with minimal or no code.

Comment: this is for a front end website therefore the grid is inappropriate for this use..this is why a webpart is the correct solution.

Comment: You can customize the grid to look anything you want. The magic is in the SPDataSource that implements the paging backend, you can use any control for the UI

Answer (score 0):

Use this a a guide for some of the classes/methods/properties you might need to use to get paging to work. Be aware that this code does not compile, i have just pulled together various code snippets that i have in my own list results framework, which includes paging, sorting, grouping and caching. It should be enough to get you started though.

```
public class PagedListResults : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart {

    protected SPPagedGridView oGrid;

    protected override void CreateChildControls() {
        this.oGrid = new SPPagedGridView();
        oGrid.AllowPaging = true;
        oGrid.PageIndexChanging += new GridViewPageEventHandler(oGrid_PageIndexChanging);
        oGrid.PagerTemplate = null;  // Must be called after Controls.Add(oGrid)
        oGrid.PagerSettings.Mode = PagerButtons.NumericFirstLast;
        oGrid.PagerSettings.PageButtonCount = 3;
        oGrid.PagerSettings.Position = PagerPosition.TopAndBottom;
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    public override void DataBind() {
        base.DataBind();

        SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
        q.RowLimit = (uint)info.PageSize;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(info.PagingInfoData)) {
            SPListItemCollectionPosition pos = new SPListItemCollectionPosition(info.PagingInfoData);
            q.ListItemCollectionPosition = pos;
        } else {
            //1st page, dont need a position, and using a position breaks things
        }
        q.Query = info.Caml;
        SPListItemCollection items = SPContext.Current.List.GetItems(q);

        FilterInfo info = null;
        string tmp = "<View></View>";
        tmp = tmp.Replace("<View><Query>", string.Empty);
        tmp = tmp.Replace("</Query></View>", string.Empty);
        info.Caml = tmp;
        info.PagingInfoData = string.Empty;
        info.CurrentPage = oGrid.CurrentPageIndex;
        info.PageSize = oGrid.PageSize;
        if (oGrid.PageIndex == 0 || oGrid.CurrentPageIndex == 0) {
            //do nothing
        } else {
            StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
            value.Append("Paged=TRUE");
            value.AppendFormat("&p_ID={0}", ViewState[KEY_PagingPrefix + "ID:" + oGrid.PageIndex]);
            info.PagingInfoData = value.ToString();
        }

        int pagecount = (int)Math.Ceiling(items.Count / (double)oGrid.PageSize);
        for (int i = 1; i < pagecount; i++) { //not always ascending index numbers
            ResultItem item = items[(i * oGrid.PageSize) - 1];
            ViewState[KEY_PagingPrefix + "ID:" + i] = item.ID;
        }

        oGrid.VirtualCount = items.Count;

        DateTime time3 = DateTime.Now;
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Data");
        DataBindListData(table, items);

        this.oGrid.DataSource = table;
        this.oGrid.DataBind();
        this.oGrid.PageIndex = oGrid.CurrentPageIndex; //need to reset this after DataBind
    }

    void oGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) {
        oGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        oGrid.CurrentPageIndex = oGrid.PageIndex;
    }
}

public class FilterInfo {
    public string Caml;
    public string PagingInfoData;
    public int CurrentPage;
    public int PageSize;
}

public class SPPagedGridView : SPGridView {

    protected override void InitializePager(GridViewRow row, int columnSpan, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) {
        pagedDataSource.AllowCustomPaging = true;
        pagedDataSource.VirtualCount = virtualcount;
        pagedDataSource.CurrentPageIndex = currentpageindex;
        base.InitializePager(row, columnSpan, pagedDataSource);
    }

    private int virtualcount = 0;
    public int VirtualCount {
        get { return virtualcount; }
        set { virtualcount = value; }
    }

    private int currentpageindex = 0;
    public int CurrentPageIndex {
        get { return currentpageindex; }
        set { currentpageindex = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out my post on how to page using SPListItemCollectionPosition, I did a component to page over lists, maybe it can help -> http://hveiras.wordpress.com/2011/11/07/listpagert-using-splistitemcollectionposition/